# Error while querying Microsoft Graph API via Postman

Tags: postman, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to call Microsoft graph Api via Postman to get users. Before calling the query, it is asking for token.
So I first generated token by giving parameters like below:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id='myclientid'
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read
&grant_type=client_credentials
&client_secret='appclientsecret'
```

This generated the access token successfully. But when I am using this token to call Microsoft Graph Api it is giving me the below error:

```
{
"error": {
"code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
"message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217",
"innerError": {
"date": "2022-05-15T14:08:00",
"request-id": "d0199a29-7223-47e9-add6-20d47ae9d5af",
"client-request-id": "d0199a29-7223-47e9-add6-20d47ae9d5af"
}
}
}
```

**Can anyone help me to solve this error.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you have generated the token by giving below **[API permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):**

[image: image1]

**After generating the token,** decode the token via [**JSON Web Tokens - jwt.io**](https://jwt.io/) and check the **`aud`** claim like below:

[image: image2]

***I tried in my environment and was able to call Microsoft graph api via Postman successfully like below:***

In **`authorization`** tag select type as **bearer token** and enter the **access token** value in **`token`** field.

[image]